# botocore 1.10.4 not compatible with python-dateutil 2.7.2

Tags: boto3

Error message on trying to install ansible script = "botocore 1.10.4 has requirement python-dateutil<2.7.0,>=2.1, but you'll have python-dateutil 2.7.2 which is incompatible."

Can someone update botocore to accommodate newest python-dateutil packages?

Script worked well in the past, I imagine many people lack the skill to install the older python-dateutil manually.

Answer (score 8):

Regarding the Error message, I don't know if someone can update the current botocore to accomodate the newest python-dateutil package. However,  you can install a compatible version of python-dateutil depending on the required compatible version by the specific packages you are trying to install.

`pip install python-dateutil==2.1`

Hope that helps.